# Order data frame by most common value in specific column

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R this is a portion of it:

```
Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629
Acss3 PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948
Nr1h4 PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638
Rarg PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288
Vdr PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479
Pamr1 PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188
```

What I'd like to achieve is ordering the data frame by the most common element (more occurrences) in the second column, this is the desired result:

```
Nr1h4 PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638
Rarg PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288
Vdr PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479
Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629
Acss3 PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948
Pamr1 PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Every comment on this post was so useful! Thank a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R way is to count the occurrence of `V2` using `table`, `sort` them in decreasing order convert it into a dataframe using `stack` and `merge` with original dataframe

```
merge(df, stack(sort(table(df$V2), decreasing = TRUE)), by.x = "V2", by.y = "ind")

#         V2     V1                 V3 values
#1 PTHR24082  Nr1h4 ENSMUSG00000047638      3
#2 PTHR24082   Rarg ENSMUSG00000001288      3
#3 PTHR24082    Vdr ENSMUSG00000022479      3
#4 PTHR24115 Kif21a ENSMUSG00000022629      2
#5 PTHR24115  Acss3 ENSMUSG00000035948      2
#6 PTHR24254  Pamr1 ENSMUSG00000027188      1
```

You can remove the `values` column which is the count of frequency for each `V2` if not needed.

In `dplyr`, we can do this with `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(V2) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  inner_join(df) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(col2) %>%
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(desc(n))
```

---

Another option is `add_count`

```
df1 %>%
  add_count(col2) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  col1   col2      col3                   n
#  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>              <int>
#1 Nr1h4  PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638     3
#2 Rarg   PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288     3
#3 Vdr    PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479     3
#4 Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629     2
#5 Acss3  PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948     2
#6 Pamr1  PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188     1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
df1[with(df1, order(-ave(seq_along(col2), col2, FUN = length))),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("Kif21a", "Acss3", "Nr1h4", "Rarg", "Vdr", 
"Pamr1"), col2 = c("PTHR24115", "PTHR24115", "PTHR24082", "PTHR24082", 
"PTHR24082", "PTHR24254"), col3 = c("ENSMUSG00000022629", "ENSMUSG00000035948", 
"ENSMUSG00000047638", "ENSMUSG00000001288", "ENSMUSG00000022479", 
"ENSMUSG00000027188")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are named A, B, C you can use the code below. This will add an `N` column to `df`, so if you don't want that, either add `df <-` at the begeninning to have this output overwrite `df`, or replace `df` with `copy(df)`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, N := .N, B][order(-N)][, -'N']

#         A         B                  C
# 1:  Nr1h4 PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638
# 2:   Rarg PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288
# 3:    Vdr PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479
# 4: Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629
# 5:  Acss3 PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948
# 6:  Pamr1 PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base:

```
df <-as.data.frame(matrix(c("Kif21a", "PTHR24115", "ENSMUSG00000022629",
"Acss3", "PTHR24115", "ENSMUSG00000035948",
"Nr1h4", "PTHR24082", "ENSMUSG00000047638",
"Rarg", "PTHR24082", "ENSMUSG00000001288",
"Vdr", "PTHR24082", "ENSMUSG00000022479",
"Pamr1", "PTHR24254", "ENSMUSG00000027188"),ncol =3, byrow = T))
```

```
      V1        V2                 V3
1 Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629
2  Acss3 PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948
3  Nr1h4 PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638
4   Rarg PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288
5    Vdr PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479
6  Pamr1 PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188
```

```
tmp <- table(df$V2)
df[order(tmp[levels(df$V2)[df$V2]], decreasing = T),]
```

```
 V1        V2                 V3
3  Nr1h4 PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000047638
4   Rarg PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000001288
5    Vdr PTHR24082 ENSMUSG00000022479
1 Kif21a PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000022629
2  Acss3 PTHR24115 ENSMUSG00000035948
6  Pamr1 PTHR24254 ENSMUSG00000027188
```